# open_by_key is stuck for long time and finally failing with error : Connection to oauth2.googleapis.com timed out

Tags: gspread

Everything was running fine till yesterday. Suddenly i started getting the issue. Any Idea what is the reason?

Code used :

```
import gspread
client = gspread.service_account(filename='<file>.json')
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '<sheet-id>'
sheet = client.open_by_key(SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID)
```